# React native Branch io deep linking in IOS not working

Tags: ios, react-native, branch.io

I have followed the set up doc of branch for react native io i.e. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native

React native Branch io deep linking is working fine for Android part and For ios part if click the banner from my website it is taking me to appstore and not the app though app is installed in device.

When copy the link getting created when user clicking on the banner and pasting it in notepad and on long press I am getting "open in your app" option and its navigating to app.

Comment: Please specify clearly and highlight - what type of help is required or what is doubt?

Comment: Please make sure that you follow all steps correctly in below link. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native Also please set your link in Associated Domain. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5ao4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5ao4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'Open in your app' option is visible on long-pressing the link on Notes app, it means that the universal links are setup fine here.

As per your query in regards to the link being redirected to the AppStore even when the app is installed, occurs when the AASA files are not being fetched by the device. This is a common issue occurring in iOS (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123554) as in when the device fails to fetch the AASA files but this is an intermittent one and can be fixed manually. Your device will also try to fetch the AASA files at certain durations so that might also solve the issue at times.

As for the manual process, would request you to check on the Branch documentation here and follow the necessary steps : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#section-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded

If the console shows as the AASA files are not getting fetched, please try uninstalling the app, restarting the device, and reinstalling the app. Recreate the method of testing for AASA once more.

PLEASE NOTE : These steps are advisable only if the SDK is integrated fine as per our docs.

Comment: promit.dey In some ios device its working for me and in some device its not working.

Comment: You can follow th apple forum regarding the issue. It occurs in some scenarios but the AASA files look to be fetched by the device at intervals or device restarts.